# Spring mvc 3 append content after "#" in the url ? for e.g. www.example.com/example#ui-tabs-4

Tags: jquery, spring, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

Here is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showMasterForm(ModelMap model)
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");        
    MasterJDBCTemplate dao = (MasterJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("masterJDBCTemplate");
    List<String> stateList = dao.getStateList();
    model.addAttribute("stateList", stateList);
    return new ModelAndView("admin/master/example","command" ,new BranchChannelMaster());
}
```

This takes me to a URL like  `www.example.com/example`. What can I do to go to `www.example.com/example#ui-tabs-4`?

I came to this situation because i am using jQuery-ui http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax and now i want to show the result in tabular format.

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery or jQueryUI? I retagged it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '#' character in HTML usually signifies an on-page anchor.  It allows you to set an anchor somewhere, then jump to it with a link on the page.  For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="#news">Go to News</a>
    <!-- ...some other HTML -->
    <a name="news" />

  <body>
</html>
```

In that example, I created a link that would jump to the "news" section of the page.  I could, then, pass the URL with #news on the end, and the browser *should* be smart enough to jump to that section of the page.

It seems to me that what you are trying to do doesn't jive with how I would expect the browser to work.  I think the browser will swallow everything after the #, expecting to see it in the page somewhere so it can jump to it.  I could be wrong, and unfortunately I am not in a position to write any test code to prove one way or not.  I would be simple enough to do, I would think.

Using your example, I would expect you should change the `@RequestMapping` to read:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example.htm#ui-tabs-4", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

That would, in theory, change your method to accept the URL pattern your suggesting.  If you wanted to make the stuff after the '#' a variable, you could do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example.htm#{tabName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showMasterForm(@PathVariable String tabName, ModelMap model) {
```

Which would create a path variable with the value of whatever you passed in after the #, baring the browser passed that to the server.

Also, keep in mind that @RequestMapping can accept regular expressions, so if you wanted to make it accept "example.html#anything" you could do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example.htm#{tabName:[a-zA-Z]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showMasterForm(@PathVariable String tabName, ModelMap model) {
```

Which would cause it to match only one or more characters a-z or A-Z.

I still do not think it will work, because I don't think anything after the '#' will be sent by the browser.

**Update**

It seems like the OP wants to RETURN a link with an #anchor in it, so that the UI will properly jump to the correct spot.

I think the best way to do this would be to return a `RedirectView`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showMasterForm(ModelMap model)
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");        
    MasterJDBCTemplate dao = (MasterJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("masterJDBCTemplate");
    List<String> stateList = dao.getStateList();
    model.addAttribute("stateList", stateList);
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("admin/master/example#ui-tabs-4", true));
}
```

The other way to do this would be to return a String instead of a ModelAndView, and return the String "redirect:admin/master/example#ui-tabs-4".

**References:**

- [15.5.3.1 RedirectView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view)
- [RedirectView JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)

Comment: I am sorry but i dont want to change the @RequestMapping  instead i want to change the redirected page

Comment: I am not sure I follow you...there is no "redirect" here.  A redirect would happen if you were sending an HTTP redirect, which you can do in Spring several ways (returning a ModelAndView with a redirect, returning a string "redirect:XXX", etc).  Your question above seems to be about anchor tags, and in the context of Spring MVC, and we servers in general, I don't think the anchor tag is sent as part of the URL, as it's a browser-side construct.  However, my post explains how one might be able to handle the anchor if it were sent.

Comment: Instead of  return new ModelAndView("admin/master/example","command" ,new BranchChannelMaster());
which gives me WEB-INF/admin/master/example.jsp    .  I want to get something like WEB-INF/admin/master/example.jsp#ui-tabs-4 What changes i need to do to my controller ?

Comment: @CodeChimp need help on this as i want to move from menu to particular page with anchor tag,  what's the controller request map and the return string.